# Revisiting the Firefox button line-height bug... any 2011 solutions?

Tags: css

The [Firefox](http://www.cssnewbie.com/input-button-line-height-bug/) line-height bug is a pain. In short, it prevents the manual setting of `line-height` on `button` elements through a browser style `line-height: normal !important` declaration that can't be reversed.

Now this is a huge pain, and in an era where hacking around browser-specific quirks is fortunately becoming decreasingly necessary, I'd hate to have to make an exception for Firefox of all browsers.

So my question now is whether there's anything I can do about it since the concession that the [above article](http://www.cssnewbie.com/input-button-line-height-bug/) made that it was basically impossible.

Here's a fiddle to play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/hBLQ7/

Open in Firefox and Chrome and observe the difference.

So is there anything we can do in this day and age?

Answer (score 2):

Can you just set the height of the button, if that's what you're after?

Comment: This didn't work for me :( I tried setting a height: 13px and computed style was 0!

Answer (score 1):

What about hacking it with top and bottom `padding` ?

#### CSS

```
button {
   padding: 25px 0;
}
```

#### Example

[image: Example]

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QMepK/).

Comment: The padding is a viable solution but lacks the precision that is afforded by enforcing a line-height. Put it this way. If I gave you `line-height: 20px; border: 0 none; padding: 15px 0;`, I could tell you without hesitation that the button would be `50px` tall in non-FF browsers, but I couldn't tell you how tall it would be in FF, and it appears that nothing will allow me to systematically do so without knowing ahead of time what FF will evaluate "normal" line-height to be.

Comment: @Steven I realise it's not perfect, but it's one method of getting something similar.

Answer (score 0):

When testing your fiddle in firefox 9, your button actually renders with the same height as the span. Using inputs of type button/submit gives the problem you describe, however: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/larsolesimonsen/TcuXS/1/)

I still haven't found a viable way around that issue..

One of the related bug reports is [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=697451).