# Firefox problems with floated span inside <button>

Tags: css, html

I have not been able to make a html5 button with a span inside of it look alike in Chrome and FF. See the link below in FF and then in Chrome. The text "Login" is verticaly centered in Chrome but in FF the text is higher up. Line height can not be changed in FF with buttons.

When I try to solve this problem without using float another problem accurs whith the line-height and using font-size:30px in the span.

Check out the problem [here](http://jsbin.com/afezem)

Oh, and I dont want to use images..

Comment: You could have just edited your question instead of deleting it and creating a new one (just for changing the link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firefox issue is this: [Revisiting the Firefox button line-height bug... any 2011 solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863828/revisiting-the-firefox-button-line-height-bug-any-2011-solutions)

You can work around it by wrapping the text inside the `button` in a `span`, and adding the `line-height` to that:

```
<button><span>LOGIN</span><span class="a">›</span></button>

button span:first-child {
    line-height:35px;
}
```

**See:** http://jsbin.com/afezem/2

Or, you might prefer to slightly abuse the `b` element: http://jsbin.com/afezem/4

```
<button><b>LOGIN</b><span>›</span></button>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution for this problem. Here is the Solution.

```
    `http://jsfiddle.net/Uysbm/`
```

Comment: Links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code and an explanation.